# Doctrine query builde add condition in where

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a query like :

```
    $qb->select('m.id', 'b.id as bId');
    $qb->leftJoin('AppBundle\Entity\Bet', 'b', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'm.id = b.match');
    //$qb->where('b.user = :user');
    //$qb->setParameters(array('user' => $user->getId()));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

With this query, I can get all rows of `m` entity and `ID` of joined entity `BET` if exist (else I get null) in `bId`

In my entity BET I have a field user.

How can I retrieve rows with `betId` is null AND if `betId` is not null, check if `b.user = :user` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, this should do the trick:

```
$qb->select('m.id', 'b.id as bId');
    ->leftJoin('AppBundle\Entity\Bet', 'b')
    ->where('b.id = NULL')
    ->orWhere('b.user = :user')
    ->setParameter('user', $user->getId())
```

I removed the "WITH" arguments, theoretically they are not needed if you defined your mapping correctly. Feel free to put them back if you want or need.